# How to call helper functions in order to determine what to return, in python?

Tags: python-3.x, helper

```
def is_win_for(self, checker):
    """ returns True if there are four consecutive slots containing
        checker on the Board
    """
    assert(checker == 'X' or checker == 'O')

    def is_horizontal_win(self, checker):
        """ Checks for a horizontal win for the specified checker.
        """
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width - 3):
                if self.slots[row][col] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row][col + 1] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row][col + 2] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row][col + 3] == checker:
                    return True
        return False

    def is_vertical_win(self, checker):
        """ checks for a vertical win for the specified checker
        """
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width - 3):
                if self.slots[row][col] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row + 1][col] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row + 2][col] == checker and \
                   self.slots[row + 3][col] == checker:
                    return True
        return False
    x = is_horizontal_win(checker)
    y = is_vertical_win(checker)
   if x == True and y == True:
       return True
```

I get the `is_horizontal_win() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checker'` error. How should I call `is_horizontal` and `is_vertical` within `is_win_for` to return either `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, functions belonging to a class need to have an associated object when called. For example, you can do `self.is_horizontal_win(checker)` or `some_obj.is_horizontal_win(checker)`.

Right now Python's saying you're missing an input because `is_horizontal_win` takes two inputs: `self` and `checker`, and it's interpreting `checker` in `x = is_horizontal_win(checker)` as the first input `self`.